# Can I put a "marker" on a QuickTime movie?

Tags: video, quicktime

Is there any way for me to put a "marker" in the timeline of a QuickTime movie? This would be very helpful in certain cases, for example quickly marking parts of long movies from my digital camera which I want to review later. I'm sure I could do this using iMovie or Final Cut Pro, but I'm looking for something specifically in QuickTime player (as I'm previewing movies taken right off my digital camera)

What I envision is something like I have mocked up in this doctored screen capture:

[image: A Marker!]

Comment: I've accepted the answer saying that no such feature exists, but I am still looking for a way to do this in case that changes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid no feature like that exists.

However, with QuickTime Pro, you can fairly easily cut out clips of a movie to save for later. You get two selection cursors, and can actually use copy and paste to yank out sections and put them into new players. It will then save them natively inside .mov containers with no need for exporting.